# string variable referencing range not being evaluated within workbookfunction SUM

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax so that my String variable *colLetter* will be evaluated within the SUM workbookfunction instead of being read as the literal text "colLetter".

*colLetter* stores Strings within a loop for each column range: "A:A", then "B:B", "C:C" and so on...

I have a function Col_Letter(integer) As String that takes an integer and returns the String of the column letter in excel that integer corresponds to. Example: Col_Letter(3) returns "C"

Right now my loop looks like so:

```
For c = 3 To lastColumn

    Dim colLetter As String
    colLetter = Col_Letter(c) & ":" & Col_Letter(c)
    Cells(lastRow + 1, c).Formula = "=SUM(colLetter)"


Next
```

I want the formula to return =SUM("A:A"), =SUM("B:B") etc...but it returns =SUM(colLetter) instead and thus #Value!

I can't figure out what needs to be fixed with my syntax of the sum formula. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Integer) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to get the letter of the column, use the number, it is faster.

Also if you try to sum the whole column with a formula in the same column you will get a circular reference error.

```
For c = 3 To lastColumn    
    Cells(lastRow + 1, c).Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(1,c),Cells(lastRow, c)).Address & ")"   

Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful.

Comment: You now need to choose **ONE** to mark as correct.  Choose the one you ended up using and click on the check mark by that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not needed if you use R1C1 reference:

```
Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Resize(, lastColumn - 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R[-1]C)"
```

---

A1 reference alternative:

```
Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Resize(, lastColumn - 2).Formula = "=SUM(C1:C" & lastRow & ")"
```

Comment: I will look into how R1C1 works- thanks for your response!

Comment: @DHagens11 `R1` is row 1, `R[-1]` is the row above the formula, and `C` without number is the same column as the formula. It will still show up as A1 style reference in the formula bar - for example `=SUM(C1:C7)`, `=SUM(D1:D7)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to alter your function like this:

```
Function Col_letter(iCol As Long) As String
    If iCol > 0 And iCol <= Columns.Count Then
        Col_letter = Evaluate("substitute(address(1, " & iCol & ", 4), ""1"", """")")
    End If
End Function
```